# How to run robocopy as non admin without having to share folders for read/write access - WINDOWS 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, robocopy

I have a basic bat file which copies files from one directory to another

```
set SOURCE=\\T4\D$\TV
set DESTINATION=\\T4\E$\TV

robocopy /MIR %SOURCE% %DESTINATION%
```

When i run as a user (member of the admin group) it just displays the contents of the bat file in a command prompt window on an endless loop.

However when i right click over the bat file and click run as administrator it executes perfectly.

When i right click over the bat file and click properties> compatibility, the option to run as administrator is greyed out for some reason?

I dont really want to share my folders either :)

Any help?

Comment: Source and Destination are the same? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Administrative shares in your for your SOURCE and DESTINATION locations, you would require Admin privileges. Not just for robocopy, but for ANY copy command.

Try going to either location from the RUN command to verify.

Comment: **1:** How do you know the OP is using Administrative shares for SOURCE and DESTINATION locations? **2:** OP clearly states that his/her user account has admin privileges.